# Would year fixed effects control for national trends in behaviour?

Tags: regression, panel-data, survey, fixed-effects-model

I have panel data on individuals followed before, during, and after the Great Recession. I study the effect of an individual experiencing unemployment on their weight gain in a fixed effects analysis. A colleague asked if the change in weight seen could instead be a consequence of people's changing attitudes to health behaviours during recessions, i.e. if the people in the country I study more generally stopped paying for gym memberships and eating expensive and healthier foods as they saw their country was in the middle of a financial crisis the population may more generally be gaining weight.

I apply year fixed effects in my analysis to control for such common shocks across years.

Would I be right in thinking that I am using the year fixed effects correctly here? To control for a common national trend in attitudes to health behaviours due to the national recession, which may be influencing weight?

Comment: It strikes me that I am doing the following by including year fixed effects: *year and industry fixed effects are included to control for unobserved time variant or industry-variant influences* Zhou, M., Li, K., & Chen, Z. (2021). Corporate governance quality and financial leverage: Evidence from China. International Review of Financial Analysis, 73, 101652.  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1057521920302933?dgcid=raven_sd_search_email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following source:

*"year fixed effects (i.e. year dummy variables) control for factors changing each year that are common to all cities for a given year."*

- Introductory Applied Econometrics
  https://are.berkeley.edu/courses/EEP118/current/handouts/eep118_panel_data_fixed_effects.pdf

I imagine this may also hold for individuals during a recession.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, there are two classes of fixed effects: entity and time. Changing behavior is something which occurs gradually over time, and it is also unobservable (to the best of my knowledge, unless you have survey data etc.). So, time fixed effects could absorb the unobservable changing attitudes of individuals over time. However, in the specific example you provided, it seems that these attitudes are conditional upon there being a recession. In this case, I am not sure whether including time fixed effects would absorb the effects of changing attitudes if they are conditional upon another variable. In addition, there could be heterogeneity in responses in terms of income, for example. I would expect the top of the income distribution to respond in a different way to a recession than the bottom.

I think in this case, time fixed effects wouldn't capture this, because the change would not be, in my estimation, constant across individuals but evolving over time, rather heterogeneous across individuals and conditional upon economic conditions. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I probably should have clarified that I also control for individual and regional fixed effects, would this help time fixed effects to control for this time trend? I should also mention that everyone in the panel was exposed to the same recession at the same time.

Comment: @John while the individuals are exposed to the same shock, their responses are heterogeneous. car safety is a variable which improves over time and is more or less constant across individuals as all cars will adhere to the new standard. This could be captured through TFE in a study on crashes, for instance. But attitudes towards eating/exercise are likely heterogeneous based on economic conditions and therefore not constant across individuals. In your case, TFE would capture generally evolving attitudes towards exercise and eating, but not conditional behavior changes in recessions, I believe

Answer (score 1):

OK, the true explanatory variable is, at times, not the year, per se, but what significant market-moving event, social movement, pandemics, ..., that are associated with a year, group of years, or even perhaps a decade or more (for example, the computer revolution, which continues to change our lives).

The latter events are the prime movers, occurring over the evolution of time displaying nearly linear or non-linear growth patterns. An associated time grouping dummy variable is a convenient, and generally useful, proxy variable.

However, this is a cautionary tale, as 'dummy variables' are not patently improperly named.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so is the implication that including year could help to control for a potential trend in attitudes to health behaviours which are time based due to an economic decline?